# С++ форматированный вывод с использованием cout

Tags: c++

Мне надо в выводе шесть 0, на С это будет так:

```
int x = 0;

printf("%06d\n", x);
```

Как это можно на плюсах оформить?

Comment: А точно так же. Он жрёт эту конструкцию. Но я думаю, что Вам нужно нечто иное...

Comment: @kff он эту конструкцию сожрет если подключить <cstdio>, а я хотел бы понять как такое можно сделать с cout

Comment: у cout есть похожие настройки

Comment: @Grundy можно подробнее или где можно почитать?

Comment: @VladimirSamoilenko Тогда напишите, что Вам нужно сделать это с использованием `cout`. Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: @kff так и сделал

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    std::cout << std::setw(6) << std::setfill('0') << x << '\n';
}
```